# Random element from list Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get a random Int from a list and I'm having some issues because the only libraries that we're allowed to use are `QuickCheck`, `GHC.IO` and  `Data.List`.

So far I managed to get a random IO Int by using:

```
ran :: Gen Int
ran = choose (0,3)
```

(The list has length=4)

But when I call

```
elem = list !! generate ran
```

I get: `Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘IO Int’`
And i'm pretty sure you can't "extract" only the Int from an IO Int so i'm kinda lost.

¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can work with an `fmap` such that `elem` is an `IO Int`:

```
elem :: IO Int
elem = fmap (list !!) (generate ran)
```

or we can work with the operator alias of `fmap`: `(<$>)`:

```
elem :: IO Int
elem = (list !!) <$> generate ran
```

It is probably better, as [@AndrewRay says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493634/random-element-from-list-haskell/67493704?noredirect=1#comment119296583_67493704), to use another name, since the `Prelude` already contains an `elem` function. For example `randElem`:

```
randElem :: IO Int
randElem = (list !!) <$> generate ran
```

Comment: That said, I'd suggest a different name than `elem`, since that's the name of a function in Prelude.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this isn't working. The list I have is this one: `list :: [Mov]` where `Mov :: (Int,Int)` and when I do this I get: `Couldn't match type ‘IO Mov’ with ‘(Int, Int)’`

Comment: To be more precise, list =[(3,3),(3,2),(2,3),(2,2)]

Comment: In that case you will need to adapt the `IO Int` type to the `IO ElementOfListType`, so here that is `IO (Int, Int)`.

Comment: Damn, i'm not allowed to do that hahaha they are prefixed...